# Slow retrieve PostGIS raster value through ST_Value

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql, postgis-raster

I have a PostGIS DB containing a set of daily raster data from 1981 up to 2021. The inserted raster tile size is 83x90.

Problem: I wanna query the data through `ST_Value` for a specified Lat Lon, however, I notice it's so slow according to the coordinate I use. The first query execution takes so long (around 1.5 minutes) to be executed but if I query again passing a Lat Lon nearby to the latest query, it is faster (around 10 sec).

Basically, this is the way I'm querying.

```
SELECT
    date,
    ST_Value(rast, 1, (ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-119.167504,44.962215 ), 4326),4326)))
FROM
    myraster 
WHERE
    AND date >= '19810101' AND date <= '20210101'
    AND ST_Intersects(rast, ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-119.167504,44.962215), 4326),4326))
```

Table:

| column | type | Nullable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | bigserial | not null |
| variable | character varying(10) | not null |
| date | date | not null |
| rast | raster | not null |
| filename | text | not null |

Explain analyze result:

```
1. Index Scan using myraster_rast_gist on myraster  (cost=0.41..7.18 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=4.881..60347.936 rows=14618 loops=1)'
2. Index Cond: ((rast)::geometry && '0101000020E61000007D04FEF0F39354C0A25D85949FA03D40'::geometry)'
3. Filter: _st_intersects('0101000020E61000007D04FEF0F39354C0A25D85949FA03D40'::geometry, rast, NULL::integer)
4. Planning time: 0.272 ms
5. Execution time: 60353.772 ms
```

Looks like the raster structure maintains a kind of cache for each query, where,  as farther away is the coordinate from the latest fetched point, the query takes so long to be executed. I'm trying to figure out a way to reduce the 1.5 minutes.

Comment: Can you show us `\d myraster` ?

Comment: Have you indexed your raster table? If not try the following: CREATE INDEX myraster_convexhull_idx ON myraster USING GIST(ST_ConvexHull(rast));

Comment: @Trashmonk Yes. I'm using GIST exactly as you described

Comment: @TimothyDalton this is the table scheme.
id:bigserial not null |
 variable:character varying(10) | 
 date:date | 
 rast:raster | 
 filename:text |

Comment: If you remove `AND date >= '19810101' AND date <= '20210101'` does it speed up the query? Can you provide what `EXPLAIN ANALYZE ...`  yields? How many records are in this table and what kind of machine are you using?

Comment: @TimothyDalton Explain analyze without the `WHERE date`. I didn't see any improvement however I also have an index on the 'date' column.
'Index Scan using myraster_rast_gist on myraster  (cost=0.41..7.18 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=4.881..60347.936 rows=14618 loops=1)'
'  Index Cond: ((rast)::geometry && '0101000020E61000007D04FEF0F39354C0A25D85949FA03D40'::geometry)'
'  Filter: _st_intersects('0101000020E61000007D04FEF0F39354C0A25D85949FA03D40'::geometry, rast, NULL::integer)'
'Planning time: 0.272 ms'
'Execution time: 60353.772 ms'

Comment: This is about 40*365 ~= 15000 rasters, correct?

Comment: Have you tried to add something like `AND rast && ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-119.167504,44.962215), 4326),4326))` ?

Comment: Thanks @bugmenot123 but sorry, I didn't really get your point. Actually, I have ~= 52704 rows each year. The number of rows of the entire table is: 2105136

Comment: a) what size of machine are you using @mkdev? b) can you share the settings you will find in https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/ c) can you try to run vacuum analyze to see if it makes a difference https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Introduction_to_VACUUM,_ANALYZE,_EXPLAIN,_and_COUNT ? d) try the query above J. Monticolo suggested

Comment: Thanks @TimothyDalton I'll explore these parameters. Maybe my setup is inapropriated based on PGTune outs. My server (not only for PG) is 32G mem, 8 Core, 1.5TB SSD. These are my actual params: shared_buffers = 4000MB, work_mem = 4000MB and default effective_io_concurrency. The PGTune out is: max_connections = 92,  shared_buffers = 1GB, effective_cache_size = 3GB, maintenance_work_mem = 256MB, checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7, wal_buffers = 16MB, default_statistics_target = 100, random_page_cost = 1.1, effective_io_concurrency = 200, work_mem = 5698kB, min_wal_size = 1GB, max_wal_size = 4GB

Comment: From what I can tell I would say the server should suffice. Did c) or d) make any difference?

Comment: The server have auto vacuum, but I ran again with `VACUUM ANALYZE myraster` and also I've put the `AND rast && ST_Transform...` but sincerely I didn't notice a notable difference. Through the pg_activity it's very clear that the first execution get stucked, but once it's finished, querying a coordinate near to the first point is very fast. I've increased a bit the work_mem, cache and buffer. I'm getting it around 1.2 ~1.3 min (10 sec better). Looks like a tile is loaded to the cache, so any point in that tile is retrieved fast.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that querying a single raster is probably very fast, but you are querying 40 years of daily rasters = ~14600 rasters. You can verify this by querying a single date.

What type of data do you need to extract? Here are some ideas:

If you are frequently querying the same time range and need to extract (say) the sum or mean for a particular point, you could consider pre-aggregating your daily data to a single raster using `ST_MapAlgebra()`

You could also experiment with a smaller tile size.

If your tiles are perfectly aligned with a common `id`, you could do a single intersect with your point to obtain the tile `id` and pixel `x` and `y`, and then use those to query your rasters.

Comment: Unfortunately, the application requires daily values, so for this case aggregation cant' be used. I think querying through the pixel `x` and `y` would help, but I don't have a unique `id` for each tile. I'm working to try it and I'll try to decrease the tile size as well. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @amball  I've performed tests using a tile size of 10x10. I've inserted the same amount of data and compared the results with my original tile size. At this analysis, with 10x10 tile it took around 1/3 time of the original one (83x90) using the same query. Apparently, it looks like a nice result. However, I notice a difference of 90 GB in the new table with the 10x10 tile. Should the smaller tile increase the table size? In the same way, is there a better way to determine the optimal tile size?

Comment: @mkdev I don't know if there is a single optimal tile size, although see the suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083732/postgis-optimal-raster-tile-size-for-spatial-join-with-census-enumeration-distr 

In general, think of this as a two stage process: (i) identify the tiles that intersect with your geometry (that should be fast if you have a spatial index), and (ii) for those tiles, identify the pixels of interest. Smaller tiles will make (ii) faster on a per-tile basis, but may return more tiles.